# FlexCel created corrupted xlsx file

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, xls, flexcel

I use the `FlexCel` library to create an Excel report in the `.xlsx` format.

When creating a file in `.xls` format - everything works fine.

When I try to create a file in the `.xlsx` format, the file is created, but when I open it by Excel, I get an error that the file is corrupt and can not be opened. And the file has the size in half from .xls.

If someone has encountered a similar problem or knows a solution, I will be very grateful for the answer.

---

Edit:
My code

```
    var templateFilePath = "D:/template.xlsx";
    var newReportPath = "D:/report.xlsx";
    using (var fr = new FlexCelReport(true))
    {
        fr.AddTable("SOReport", dataTable);
        fr.Run(
            templateFilePath,
            newReportPath
        );
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are using the wrong extension.  You cannot rename an xls to xlsx and expect it to work.  The formats are different.  To create an xlsx you must open the xls in excel and then save it to xlsx.

Comment: Given it is half the size it seems reasonable to assume the file hasn't just been renamed @jdweng.

Comment: Flexdcellis checking the file extension and saving it in a different format which accounts for the file size change.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with export in `xlsx` format with old versions of FlexCel.

Currently I've tested it on **FlexCel v5.5.1.0** and there is interesting behaviour:
If I use Excel 2016 or above to create xlsx templates - then I get "file is corrupted" error while trying to open exported xlsx file.

But if I use **Excel 2013 or below** to create xlsx templates - then I can open it perfectly without errors.

*Also mention that if you open xlsx template created by Excel 2013 or below in Excel 2016 or above and save it - you can't restore it to working state in the future. **Template will lost for you.***

Too late but I hope this can help you.

---

P.S. Probably, FlexCel team (TMS Software) fixed it starting with v6.7.16.0 version of FlexCel. I think so because documentation said something similar: https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp?s=history
Points like `Improved : Improved compatibility with invalid xls and xlsx files`
But I can't argue that.

Comment: Thank you for this, I started to believe I am paranoid with the same behaviour :-D
I have old framework using FlexCel 5.7.6 which I cannot change. I used Office 365 to change the template and ended up with broken file after filling it with FlexCel.
Now I tried to just resave the same template in Excel 2016 and fortnunately everything works.